# How to take the difference between the resulting and the correct bucket of a one hot vector into account?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Hi I am using tensorflow at my university to try to classify steering angles of a simulation program using only the images the simulation produces.

The Steering angles are values from -1 to 1 and I separated them into 50 "buckets". So the first value of my prediction vector would mean that the predicted steering angle is between -1 and -0.96.
The following shows the classification and optimization functions I am using.

```
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(prediction, y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001).minimize(cost)
```

y is a vector that with 49 zeros and a single 1 for the correct bucket. My question now is. 
How do I take into account if e.g. the correct bucket is at index 25, that the a prediction of 26 is much better than a prediction of 48.

I didn't post the actual network since it is just a couple of conv2d and maxpool layers with a fully connected layer at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are applying Cross entropy or negative log likelihood. you are penalizing the system given the predicted output and the ground truth.

So saying that your system predicted different numbers on your 50 classes output and the highest one was the class number 25 but your ground truth is class 26. So your system will take the value predicted on 26 and adapt the parameters to produce the highest number on this output the next time it sees this input.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I understand what you are saying, but what action would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

You could do two basic things:

Change your y and prediction to be scalars in the range -1..1; make the loss function be (y-prediction)**2 or something. A very different model, but perhaps more reasonable that the one-hot.

Keep the one-hot target and loss, but have y = target*w, where w is a constant matrix, mostly zeros, 1s on the diagonal, and smaller values on the next diagonal, elements (e.g. y(i) = target(i) * 1. + target(i-1) * .5 + target(i+1) * .5 + ...); kind of gross, but it should converge to something reasonable.

Comment: Yeah the first option is the one I was thinking about too. My question now is what activation function function I would have to use in the output layer to get values between -1 and 1. The second option is really really interesting. Thank you very much I will think about it.